# Удалить get параметр через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Как удалить из URL

```
http://site.ru/catalog/?store=y&selection=p&set_filter=Y&PAGEN_2=1
```

через **.htaccess** параметр ***store=y***

т.е чтобы получилось

```
http://site.ru/catalog/?selection=p&set_filter=Y&PAGEN_2=1
```

пытаюсь сделать так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^store=y [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Оформите код как полагается. И приведите вид URL, который хотите получить.

Comment: смысла нет в таких реврайтах. редактируйте скрипты и шаблоны.

Answer (score 1):

Вы удаляете всю query, когда пишите `$1?`. Вам надо забрать оттуда все, кроме store. Можно попробовать таким образом. Если вам нужно конкретное значение, подставьте его вместо `[^&]+`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)store=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Давно искал подобное решение! 
Работает, но не во всех случаях. В ссылке с UTM метками, GET параметр из ссылки удаляется, но круглые скобки {} преобразуются в набор символов.

Пример:

```
http://site.ru/page/catalog/predmet-123?&utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=rsy&utm_campaign=new&utm_content=predmet-123&utm_term=%7bkeyword%7d&region_name=%7bregion_name%7d&device=%7bdevice_type%7d
```

Должно быть так:

```
http://site.ru/page/catalog/predmet-123?&utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=rsy&utm_campaign=kredit&utm_content=predmet-123&utm_term={keyword}&region_name={region_name}&device={device_type}
```

Интересно было бы узнать верное решение.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cmpl=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```